# AngularJS/Flash (how to embed flash video in angular html partial)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, actionscript-3, flash

I have been going around in circles trying to embed a flash game in an angular html partial - I have the game loading without any errors, except when I right click on the blank flash screen, it says "movie not loaded." I have used https://github.com/Pleasurazy/angularjs-media, as well as trying another directive somebody made on github (having trouble finding the link right now). The github page that I can't find used `swfobject` - `angularjs-media` doesn't seem to need that. If somebody could please just help me get my flash video embedded onto my angular html partial - I would greatly appreciate it...thanks!

Let me know if you want to see my code!

Comment: Check swf file' url , it is simply cannot find it. You can set absolute path for checking, like: `<flash width="270" height="60" src="http://www.yourdomainname.com/files/flashfile.swf"></flash>`

Comment: @Cherniv its not that - i am already using the absolute path - and the .swf loads fine (i can see it in network tab on browser) it is just blank - I am starting to think that I missed some sort of export option in flash cc that makes it work...any ideas?

Comment: @Cherniv i am developing locally...so my absolute path is just the path on my computer - not www.domain.com - is this right?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/SqzJv8tKvvXH50Hy7eiD?p=preview shows that angularjs-media does work

Comment: @ShawnC thanks - looking at it, I see you aren't using it with the ng-view directive (you are just putting it in index.html...no partial) - i think the hold up is with putting it in a partial that then gets displayed in ng-view div

Comment: @ShawnC. thanks for your help - i ended up rebuilding my whole site around the angularjs-media demo and I got it working...as far as I can tell - the error was cause by not having `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');` in the config function for angular app (where the angular routes are), coupled with using `<a href=/link>` instead of `<a href=/#!/link>` - any reason why? it must be something deep routed in angular.

Comment: @ShawnC. I'm having another problem now with chrome not being able to display my flash game correctly when I use ng-include in the same partial - here is the link to the stack question if you want to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703865/tail-on-flash-game-graphic-when-using-ng-include-no-tail-on-graphic-without

Comment: @ShawnC. I saw you used $stateProvider instead of $routeProvider - why?

Comment: @ewizard you use the stateProvider with the ui-router

Comment: @ShawnC. thanks - good to know - i ended up taking a slightly different approach - thanks for your help.

Comment: @ShawnC. if you want credit for your plunkr just answer the question and post the plunkr link in the answer...thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments in the question.

http://plnkr.co/edit/SqzJv8tKvvXH50Hy7eiD?p=preview

Comment: Please consider putting the answer *into the answer*!

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, but I came here looking for the same answer.  I tried angularjs-media but it didn't work, perhaps because my Flash app uses a webcam.  I then found this bower component:

```
bower install w11k-flash
```

It worked well even as a directive embedded in another directive. The code for the component is here: http://w11k.github.io/w11k-flash/.