# Tail on flash game graphic when using ng-include, no tail on graphic without

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, flash, express

I just embedded a flash game on my website (angular/node/express) using http://ngmodules.org/modules/angularjs-media like this:

```
<div class="container hero-unit">
  <flash width="400" height="300" src="files/avoider.swf"></flash>
</div>
```

The thing is, I have a navigation bar that I want to include in the same partial with `ng-include` like this:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/navbar'"></div>

<div class="container hero-unit">
  <flash width="400" height="300" src="files/avoider.swf"></flash>
</div>
```

When I do so, however, instead of the graphics moving normally in the flash game, there is a constant repeating tail for the image. Meaning, when the image moves - a copy of the image is left behind in the last location - so it looks like a really long tail. I know that ng-include is causing this problem, but I don't know why...any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks.

**UPDATE**

The tail only happens in chrome, it works normally in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was causing the problem:

```
'<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />'
```

It was in the `angularjs-media` directive file where the html for the `<object>` tag is created - chrome don't like it. It makes the flash window transparent.